# H2O: Deep learning object not found in function 'predict' for argument 'model'

Tags: r, h2o

I'm just testing out h2o, in particular its deep learning capabilities, since I've heard great things about it. So far I've been using the following code:

```
     library(h2o)
library(caret)
data("iris")

# Initiate H2O --------------------
h2o.removeAll() # Clean up. Just in case H2O was already running
h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size="22G")  # Start an H2O cluster with all threads available

# Get training and tournament data -------------------
a <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[a,]
test <- iris[-a,]

# Convert target to factor -------------------
target <- as.factor(iris$Species)

feature_names <- names(train)[1:(ncol(train)-1)]

train_h2o <- as.h2o(train)
test_h2o <- as.h2o(test)

prob <- test[, "id", drop = FALSE]

model_dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = feature_names, y = "target", training_frame = train_h2o, stopping_metric = "logloss")
h2o.logloss(model_dl)

pred_dl <- predict(model_dl, newdata = tourn_h2o)
prob <- cbind(prob, as.data.frame(pred_dl$p1, col.names = "dl"))
write.table(prob[, c("id", "dl")], paste0(model_dl@model_id, ".csv"), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = c("id", "probability"))
```

The relevant part is really that last line, where I got the following error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'DeepLearning_model_R_1494350691427_70' not found in function: predict for argument: model
```

Has anyone come across this before? Are there any easy solutions to this that I might be missing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: With the updated code I get the error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Illegal argument(s) for DeepLearning model: DeepLearning_model_R_1494428751150_1.  Details: ERRR on field: _train: Training data must have at least 2 features (incl. response).
ERRR on field: _stopping_metric: Stopping metric cannot be logloss for regression.
```

I assume this has to do with the the way the Iris dataset is being read in.

Comment: You have to build your model before you can predict with it.  Your code above never builds a model.  for example  `myModel <- h2o.gbm(...)` then `predict(myModel, ...)` This may have just been a mistake while drafting your question.

Comment: @IanWesley Yep, sorry missed a line. I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you edit your code example so that it's a reproducible example? You can use a public dataset, or even iris.  It should be quick to debug once I can run the code...

Comment: @ErinLeDell Hey Erin sure thing, I'll update that now.

Answer (score 1):

Answer To First Question: Your original error message sounds like one you can get when things get of sync. E.g. maybe you had two sessions running at once, and removed the model in one session; the other session wouldn't know its variables are now out of date. H2O allows multiple connections, but they have to be co-operative. (Flow - see next paragraph - counts as a second session.)

Unless you can make a reproducible example, shrug and put it down to gremlins, and start a new session. Or, go and look at the data/models in Flow (a web server always running on 127.0.0.1:54321 ), and see if something is no longer there.

For your EDIT question, your model is making a regression model, but you are trying to use logloss, so thought you were doing a classification. This is caused by not having set the target variable to be a factor. Your current `as.factor()` line is on the wrong data, in the wrong place. It should go after your `as.h2o()` lines:

```
train_h2o <- as.h2o(training)  #Typo fix
test_h2o <- as.h2o(test)

feature_names <- names(training)[1:(ncol(training)-1)]  #typo fix
y = "Species" #The column we want to predict

train_h2o[,y] <- as.factor(train_h2o[,y])
test_h2o[,y] <- as.factor(test_h2o[,y])
```

And then make the model with:

```
model_dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = feature_names, y = y, training_frame = train_h2o, stopping_metric = "logloss")
```

Get predictions with:

```
pred_dl <- predict(model_dl, newdata = test_h2o)  #Typo fix
```

And compare with correct answer with the prediction using:

```
cbind(test[, y], as.data.frame(pred_dl$predict))
```

(BTW, H2O always detects the Iris data set columns as numeric vs. factor perfectly, so the above `as.factor()` lines are not needed; your error message must've been on your original data.)

StackOverflow advice: test your reproducible example, in full, and copy and paste in that exact code, with the exact error message that code is giving you. Your code had numerous small typos. E.g. `train` in places, `training` in others. `createDataPartition()` was not given; I assumed `a = sample(nrow(iris), 0.8*nrow(iris))`. `test` has no "id" column.

Other H2O advice:

- Run `h2o.removeAll()` *after* `h2o.init()`. It was giving you an error message if run before.  (Personally I avoid that function - it is the kind of thing that gets left in a production script by mistake...)
- Consider importing your data into h2o earlier, and using `h2o.splitFrame()` to split it. I.e. avoid doing things in R that H2O can easily handle.
- Avoid having your data in R, at all, if you can. Prefer importFile() over as.h2o().

The thinking beyond both the last points is that H2O will scale beyond the memory of one machine, while R won't. It also is less confusing than trying to keep track of the same thing in two places.

Comment: I am getting errors even after shurring down and restarting. Is there a way to run h2o from R to protect against this problem? I mean, some way to isolate H2O to have only one totally separate H2O instances per script? Would I need totally separate jar files?

Comment: @Hack-R That deserves to be its own question. (You can run multiple instances, by putting each on a different ip/port combination, but usually it is not a good idea, and without knowing more about the errors you see, my guess is that it wouldn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but could resolve it quite easily.

My error occured because I read in an h2o-object before initialising the h2o-cluster. So I trained an h2o-model, saved it, shut down the cluster, loaded in the model and then initialized the cluster once again.

Before reading in the h2o-object, you should already initialize the cluster (h2o.init()).